# function call(methods) between native and managed C++

Tags: c++, .net, hook, marshalling

I am new to .Net and hitting the brick wall trying to resolve this....
Having done enough googling  for the past few days I've come across nothing but some vague (at lease for me) C# related info

Basically, I am trying to set up a few global hooks to carry out certain automation process. Since the development environment is VS2008 C++ windows forms, I started by compiling a native Dll  to be injected by the calling prog. The strategy being for the callback proc in native dll calling a function in .Net program (or maybe a wrapper managed dll), passing the filtered raw data (keyboard/mouse/WM_create/etc) messages for further processing.

Question: How do I pass on the handle of such function(s) to my injected dll?

Is the managed wrapper dll path an easier choice or simply have the managed & native functions residing side by side in the main application?

I'll have to do a lot of Marshalling which is yet another dark side of the matter. Is there a link to precise documentation/examples of marshalling functions?

I thank you for your help in advance.
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 'Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate'

Comment: Thanks Loki for prompt reply. I just looked it up at MSDN and appears to be the right one for passing the pointer which I shall shortly test and verify it. But of course I shall need to get hold of the right info to marshal the native dll calls to managed section.

Comment: The last comment was addressed at Paul and not Loki... sorry....Give a man a "meal" and he won't be hungry for a day. Show him how or where to get the meal, you have fed him for life!!  so the question is partly unanswered nevertheless I am grateful.

Comment: No problem. There wasn't much more to say since your question is not specific enough to give an elaborate answer... Ask again if you've got more "meal" to feed the hungry...